# how to add multiple textview with imageview in edittext in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-custom-view

I want to add multiple textview with imageview in edittext in android . I am able to add one textvew with an imageview in edittext in android by the following code .

```
ClickableSpan clickSpan = new ClickableSpan() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) { 
                   Log.v("clicked", view.getClass().getSimpleName());

                 //  int i = ((EditText) view).getSelectionStart();
                 //  int j = ((EditText) view).getSelectionEnd();
                //   phoneNum.getText().replace(Math.min(i, j ),
                  //         Math.max(i, j ), "", 0, "".length());

               }

           };

         final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
         TextView tv = createContactTextView(contactname);
         View view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contact_layout,null);
         TextView tv1 =  (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
         tv1.setText(contactname);
         BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) convertViewToDrawable(view1);
         bd.setBounds(0, 0, bd.getIntrinsicWidth(),bd.getIntrinsicHeight());

         sb.append(contactname + ",");
         sb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bd), sb.length()-(contactname.length()), sb.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
         autoCompleteTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
         sb.setSpan(clickSpan, sb.length(),
                         sb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
         autoCompleteTextView.setText(sb);



     public TextView createContactTextView(String text){
          TextView tv = new TextView(this);
          tv.setText(text);
          tv.setTextSize(20);
          tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.bubble);
          tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,android.R.drawable.presence_offline, 0);
          return tv;
    }

     public static Object convertViewToDrawable(View view) {
          int spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
          view.measure(spec, spec);
          view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
          Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
          Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
          c.translate(-view.getScrollX(), -view.getScrollY());
          view.draw(c);
          view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
          Bitmap cacheBmp = view.getDrawingCache();
          Bitmap viewBmp = cacheBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
          view.destroyDrawingCache();
          return new BitmapDrawable(viewBmp);
        }
```

By the above code I have the following layout . 
 [image]

How can I add multiple textview with imageview like the following layout ?

[image]

I have done this with autocompletetextview . After inserting one textview with imageview , the suggesstion of autocompletetextview is stopped . How can I start auto-suggestion of autocompletetextview again? How can I insert multiple textview with imageview in autocompletetextview?

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdhBg.png):

Comment: I think you are looking sonthing like this : https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2566

Comment: no I am looking an example of ImageSpan

Comment: Google plz smth like "android chips". All information you need is already on stackoverflow.